# Input dynamically generated file name

Tags: macros, strings

The situation is a bit weird and actually an excerpt from a large task.

I want to remove the last two characters from the file name (`\jobname`) and input another file with a name with these-two-character-removed-name.

While the last two character removal works file, the processing stops at the `\input` command.

For example, consider the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stringstrings}

\begin{document}

% Remove the last two characters from the file name

\newtoks\tn

\tn = {\substring[v]{\jobname}{1}{$-2}}

% The following correctly prints the result in the output 
\the\tn

% However the following does not work.
 \input{\the\tn}

\end{document}
```

Let's say that the above code file is named `mainpartAB.tex`.

While we can get an output of `mainpart`, the `\input` command,
supposed to input a file named `mainpart.tex` simply stops infinitely
only to be salvaged by a brake.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: Try `\showthe\tn` then you will see the problem. Your command is not expandable, you can't use it for an input.

Comment: With traditional TeX-engines the case of a filename containing characters whose encoding takes more than a single byte might require special attention. Thus your question inspired me to ask another question: [Can you detect from within TeX how the name of a file accessed by TeX is encoded?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/636576/118714).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the expl3 command `\str_range:Nnn` it is expandable:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\newcommand\stringrange{}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN\stringrange\str_range:Nnn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\input{\stringrange\jobname{1}{-3}}

\end{document}
```