# Can you detect from within TeX how the name of a file accessed by TeX is encoded?

Tags: tex-core, filesystem-access

*This question is inspired by the question [Input dynamically generated file name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/636488/118714) which basically is about truncating a given filename/the expansion of `\jobname` by two characters.*

In utf-8 the byte-sequence e0 a3 a9 encodes a single character, namely the "ARABIC CURLY KASRATAN".

In latin 1/iso-8859-1 the same byte-sequence, e0 a3 a9, encodes three characters, namely the characters
"small letter a, grave", "pound sterling symbol", "copyright symbol", i.e., à£©.

Thus, if the name of a file consists of that byte-sequence, different TeX-engines interprete this differently:

Traditional 8-bit-encoding TeX-engines interprete this as if the file-name consisted of three character-tokens.

utf-8-based TeX-engines like XeTeX/LuaTeX interprete this as if the file-name consisted of a single character-token.

You can easily test this.

Assume you work on an utf-8-platform and have a .tex-file whose name consists of the "ARABIC CURLY KASRATAN"-character.

I.e., *⟨ARABIC CURLY KASRATAN⟩*.tex, with the following content:

```latex
\def\splitchars#1{\ifx\relax#1\else(#1)\expandafter\splitchars\fi}
\message{\expandafter\splitchars\jobname\relax}
\bye
```

I.e., each character of the expansion of `\jobname`/of the file-name shall be displayed nested in parentheses.

When switching the encoding of the shell to latin-1/iso-8859-1,

- using traditional TeX you get the following console output:

  ```
  This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=tex)
  (./^^e0^^a3^^a9.tex (^^e0)(^^a3)(^^a9) )
  No pages of output.
  Transcript written on ^^e0^^a3^^a9.log.
  ```

  Notice that you have three parenthese-groups, `(^^e0)(^^a3)(^^a9)`, indicating that the traditonal engine assumes that the expansion of `\jobname` consists of three character-tokens. (Inside parentheses the character in question is displayed in `^^`-notation.)
- using XeTeX or LuaTeX you get the following console output:

  ```
  This is LuaTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020) 
  restricted system commands enabled.
  (./à£©.tex (à£©))
  warning  (pdf backend): no pages of output.
  Transcript written on à£©.log.
  ```

  Notice that you have a single parenthese-group, `(à£©)`, indicating that the utf8-based engine assumes that the expansion of `\jobname` consists of a single character-token. (As the encoding of the shell is switched to latin1/iso-8859-1, inside the parentheses you see the latin-1-representation of the byte-sequence that forms that single utf-8-character.)

Thus, if you want to do things with filenames reliably, e.g., removing the last two characters, information is needed on how that filename is encoded.

So the question is:

Can you detect from within TeX how the name of a file accessed by TeX is encoded?

Comment: On Unix systems, a file name is just a sequence of (8-bit) bytes, none of them 47 (slash) or 0 (NUL). May even contain control characters—it definitely does not need to be valid UTF-8 or Latin-1. Technically it is a mistake to assume that it is text in some encoding. If you assume it *is* text, then you'd have to implement something like [chardet](https://github.com/chardet/chardet) in TeX. But even then: what do you mean by removing the "last two characters" of, say, त्रिचक्रि? (See: [Text rendering hates you](https://gankra.github.io/blah/text-hates-you/#text-isnt-individual-characters).)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR **Does this imply that the `\jobname`-primitive is a technical/conceptual error?** `\jobname` returns character tokens which represent the stem of the name of , e.g., the .log-file created during the tex-run. If the `-jobname`-option does not specify otherwise, `\jobname` also represents the stem of the name of the main .tex-input-file. Which/how many character tokens are returned by `\jobname` depends on whether the TeX engine in use assumes single-byte encoding or utf8 as multibyte encoding. ...

Comment: @ShreevatsaR ... multibyte encoding. **It seems, with `\jobname` (the stem of) a file name is viewed as a text or character sequence in a particular encoding which is representable by means of character tokens.**

Comment: In Knuthian TeX there are many sections marked as system depdent, including file names, what characters are allowed in a file name, how file names are parsed.  If an implementor allows filenames with UTF-8/multi-byte encoded characters but the TeX engine itself can only deal with 8 bit character tokens, the implementor has to decide how to expand `\jobname` to a sequence of 8 bit character tokens.
And yes, TeX is a program written in the old time with characters/letters coded using only 7 bits resp. 8 bits (e.g., ASCII, EBCDIC, ISO Latin-...).